# Necessary and Sufficient Conditions for $p_1p_2 \leq q_1q_2$

Tags: inequality

Given that $p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2$ are all non-negative and that $p_1 + p_2 = q_1 + q_2$, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions that $p_1p_2 \leq q_1q_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Let the common value for the sum be $p_1 + p_2 = q_1 + q_2 = 2x $ and without loss of generality assume that $p_1 \le p_2$ and $q_1 \le q_2$.  I claim that the necessary and sufficient condition is that $\delta_1 =x - p_1 \ge x - q_1 = \delta_2 \implies p_1 \le q_1$. For seeing this, note that:
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
p_1p_2 - q_1q_2 & = (x- \delta_1)(x + \delta_1) - (x- \delta_2)(x + \delta_2) \\
& = \delta_2^2 - \delta_1^2
\end{split} 
\end{equation}$$
and thus, $p_1p_2 \le q_1q_2 \leftrightarrow \delta_2 \le \delta_1$.

The idea for this is quite natural since the maximum of the product of two non-negative numbers with constant positive sum is maximum when they are equal, so the product in general is higher when the deviation of the numbers from the mean is less. So, the necessary and sufficient condition here which is quite basic is

$$\min\{p_1, p_2\} \le \min\{q_1,q_2\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Given $p_1+p_2=q_1+q_2$ for positive variables, then
$$p_1 p_2 \le q_1 q_2 \iff \log p_1 + \log p_2 \le \log q_1 + \log q_2 \iff (p_1, p_2) \succ (q_1, q_2)$$
by Karamata's inequality and strict concavity of $\log$ function.

P.S. Here, $(p_1, p_2) \succ (q_1, q_2) \iff |p_1 - p_2| \ge |q_1-q_2| \iff f(p_1)+f(p_2) \ge f(q_1)+f(q_2)$ 
for any strictly convex function (like $x^2, x^\pi, \frac1x$), so you have a lot of equivalent ways of writing **"the"** necessary and sufficient conditions, as evidenced from the other posts already here.